# How Can I Convert Object with Multiple Properties into Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

Please I am trying to convert this object returned from my Web API:

```
[
    {"a":65,"b":59,"c":80,"d":81,"e":56,"f":55,"g":40},
    {"a":28,"b":48,"c":40,"d":19,"e":86,"f":27,"g":90}
]
```

Into array of this format inside AngularJS Controller:

```
[
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
]
```

I researched extensively & applied multiple approaches e.g. using:

1. `var arr = $.map(o, function(el) { return el; })`
2. `var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) { return o[k] });`
3. `var obj = JSON.parse(json);`
4. `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) { arr[key] = obj[key] });`

But none of the above worked as all I got from console.log was:

> [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Looks easy enough. [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) + [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: One thing to note is that there's no order to the properties of an object. So the arrays may have the properties in any order.

Comment: @Barmar eh, well, that isn't entirely true anymore. I still wouldn't trust the order presented unless i controlled the creation of the object, but the order is specified now.

Comment: @KevinB Did ES6 add order to objects? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Barmar well, it's a bit... undefined. It's not specified in the spec yet that I know of, but all modern browsers will give you object keys in insertion order with the exception of object keys that are integer-like. Integer-like keys in some browsers will be ordered in ascending order. Here's a somewhat related chrome bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work with any array of key/value objects.

```js
function convert(data) {
  let res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let keys = Object.keys(data[i]);
    let temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
      temp.push(data[i][keys[j]]);
    }
    res.push(temp);
  }
  return res;
}

var json = [
    {"a":65,"b":59,"c":80,"d":81,"e":56,"f":55,"g":40},
    {"a":28,"b":48,"c":40,"d":19,"e":86,"f":27,"g":90}
];



console.log(convert(json));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that way

```
[{"a":65,"b":59,"c":80,"d":81,"e":56,"f":55,"g":40}, 
{"a":28,"b":48,"c":40,"d":19,"e":86,"f":27,"g":90}
].map(function(n) { 
   return Object.keys(n).map(function(nn) { return n[nn] });
});
```